# Environment.UserName when using Microsoft account

Tags: .net, clr, base-class-library

Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

I notice that when the user uses a Microsoft account, there is still a local machine account that matches the one returned by `System.Environment.UserName`.

Is there a way to find the Microsoft account that is in use?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user's Microsoft account by getting the principal name for the user. This will usually be the emailaddress altough documentation states that this will not always be the case.

```
var principalName = await Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.GetPrincipalNameAsync();
```

[Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.GetPrincipalNameAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getprincipalnameasync?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp)